# How to show Google Map marker dynamically in a Laravel view page?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, laravel-5.1

I found some JavaScript code on the internet. It's helping me to store the latitude and longitude of a place, from the Google Map by moving the marker on my database table.

Database column names are `la|lo`. Now I want to show the location on a view page. The map should have these properties `frameborder="0"`,  `scrolling="no"`, `marginheight="0"`, `marginwidth="0"`, `width="250"`,  `height="272"`.

I'm a novice and I have poor knowledge on JavaScript. I'm providing the js code of registering the latitude and longitude.

```
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
<script>
function initialize() {
    var latitude = 23.786758526804636;
    var longitude = 90.39979934692383;
    var zoom = 11;

    var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

  var mapProp = {
    center: LatLng,
    zoom:12,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: LatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Drag Me!',
      draggable: true
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {

      document.getElementById('la').value = event.latLng.lat();
      document.getElementById('lo').value = event.latLng.lng();



});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

        <div id="googleMap" style="width:auto;height:400px;"></div>

        <input type="hidden" id="la" name="la">
        <input type="hidden" id="lo" name="lo">
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please post some code of the controller method and view file, so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated the lat/long are in the database, you can just retrieve it and set it on a array list in js. After that, you'll just need to iterate the list to [add markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) based on it.

The code here is from the official documentation provided.

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

For styling, you can check out the [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) page in the official documentation. It should be sufficient enough with what you want to set in your post.